# C3.js responsive x axis timeseries

Tags: responsive-design, c3.js

I'm trying to create a graph that can look good on both mobile and desktop using c3 (http://c3js.org/).

However, I'm having trouble getting the x-axis, which is a timeseries, to display change size for mobile. The only way I've managed to do this is by destroying the graph and re-creating it from scratch. But this prevents me from adding a nice transition to the chart, which would be really nice to have.
[![desktop view][1]][1]

I tried using the tick culling option on the x axis and set a max value of 8, but this option gets ignored when using either **flush()** or **resize()** methods.

So my question is: **is there any way to change the x axis values without having to destroy the graph and re-generate it?**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pcqP.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the `onresized: function () {...}`

or you can use the `onresize: function () { ... }`

[link](http://c3js.org/reference.html#onresize)

to change the culling max on resized screen:

```
        axis: {
            x: {
                 type: 'timeseries',
                 tick: {
                    culling: true,
                    format: '%m-%d',
                    fit:true,
                    culling: {
                        max: window.innerWidth > 500 ? 8 : 5
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        onresized: function () {
            window.innerWidth > 500 ? chart.internal.config.axis_x_tick_culling_max = 8 : chart.internal.config.axis_x_tick_culling_max = 5;
        },
```

Here a example: https://jsfiddle.net/07s4zx6c/2/

Answer (score 0):

add **mediaquery** according to device size

like this.

```
@media screen and (max-width:810px) {
    .c3 svg { font: .8em sans-serif; }
}
```